# Restore Point Name not shown after running in batch file

Tags: backup

[image]I used the code to create system restore point but the input name does not shown. It shows "AUTOMATED RESTORE POINT" instead. Please advise where went wrong. Thanks.

```
@echo off
mode con cols=60 lines=30 >nul 

REM Create System Restore Point
Echo System Restore Point Creation
set /p point=Enter ReStore Point Name : 
wmic.exe /Namespace:\\root\default Path SystemRestore Call CreateRestorePoint "%point%", 100, 
7
ping /n 10 localhost>nul
```

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, if you use this PowerShell command `Get-ComputerRestorePoint`, you'll see the custom description in the output.

Comment: Also, since `wmic.exe` is being deprecated by Microsoft, it might be best to switch to PowerShell exclusively.  For example, call `Checkpoint-Computer -Description "Your description here" -RestorePointType APPLICATION_INSTALL`, or continue calling WMI directly: `Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace  'root/DEFAULT' -ClassName 'SystemRestore' -MethodName 'CreateRestorePoint' -Arguments @{'Description'="My custom restore point at $((Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').ToString())"; 'EventType'= [uint32]100; 'RestorePointType' = [uint32]0}`.  Note: You may be limited to 1 restore point per day.

Comment: Hi leeharvey1, the ps checkpoint-computer option works. The second option ran and seemed no error but unable to find that restore point ? See my updated picture.

Comment: What’s the exact command you ran?

Comment: I ran exactly as is.